# GitLab-Runner cannot clone from local GitLab

Tags: docker, gitlab

This is my setup:

I run GitLab using Docker an expose it on port 10080 to my machine.
I have a gitlab-runner on my machine that is configured to use the Docker executor.

When I connect the runner to my GitLab instance, I use `localhost:10080` as the URL which works fine.

When the runner runs a job inside a Docker container, it tries to clone the code from `localhost:10080` which obviously fails since it's inside a container and localhost does not refer to my local machine.

Now what are my options? Docker for Mac has a `host.docker.internal` DNS entry that refers to the host machine when inside a container but I can't use it when I register the runner because the runner runs directly on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me but could depend on the system.

In `~/.gitlab-runner/config.toml` under the `[runners.docker]` config, I just needed to add `extra_hosts = ["localhost:172.17.0.1"]` to override the IP for `localhost`. The `172.17.0.1` IP might vary on other peoples machine.